# Melhor caminho de alta disponibilidade para minha necessidade

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Tenho estudado bastante sobre alta disponibilidade no SQL Server, nas suas mais diversas opções, que o SQL Server possui. Porém até agora não consegui encontrar a solução que atenda melhor minha necessidade.

Meu cenário:

Preciso atender uma rede de lojas, no caso 30 lojas, normalmente trabalho com meu banco no *cloud* da Amazon e todos trabalham online. O problema é que a rede tem que ser gerenciada de uma forma única (apenas um banco de dados, com todos os movimentos, etc.. etc..), mas as lojas tem sérios problemas de infra-estrutura quanto a internet, muitas interrupções no serviço.

Além das frequentes interrupções no serviço, quando está ativo, a conexão é de péssima qualidade, o que me faz desejar trabalhar prioritariamente offline e "sincronizando" os dados para uma base online. Sei que essa não é uma solução de alta disponibilidade. Mas estou meio perdido quanto a pra qual solução que devo caminhar.

1. O SQL Server possui alguma solução que me ajude com isso?
2. Trabalhar offline nessa minha situação é o ideal?
3. Qual caminho seguir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pergunta fala em alta disponibilidade e em centralização de dados remotos, e você logo já adianta que não pode contar com conexão de alta disponibilidade.

Se as lojas não possuem conexão de alta disponibilidade, e você já disse que não possuem, então não há opção senão cada loja trabalhar **offline** ou **"casualmente conectada"**, certo?

### Sincronização casual

Uma solução para isso é cada loja trabalhar como se fosse completamente independente, com seu próprio banco de dados, enviando quando possível uma parte dos seus dados que sejam do interesse de alguém em outro lugar - no caso, uma base de dados centralizada.

O recurso do **Microsoft SQL Server** que pode te ajudar com isso é a [**replicação**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198(v=sql.105).aspx). Nesta arquitetura, cada loja tem o seu próprio servidor de banco de dados e quando estiverem online sincronizam seus dados com uma base de dados central.

Você pode escolher o que enviar e o que receber, de modo que cada loja pode por exemplo enviar apenas o seu movimento e receber apenas o cadastro de produtos ou regras de preço atualizadas, ou seja, não é necessariamente um espelhamento - cada loja não precisa receber a movimentação de todas as demais.

Você também tem a opção de implementar um mecanismo semelhante por contra própria.

Se você desenhar o sistema e o banco de dados prevendo esta arquitetura, você fica livre para usar qualquer mecanismo de sincronização ou integração, e fica livre inclusive para modificar este mecanismo no futuro sem precisar de grandes alterações no restante do sistema.

### Uma abordagem possível ao desenhar um sistema distribuído casualmente conectado

A boa notícia é que um sistema e um banco de dados bem desenhados já suportarão de maneira transparente esta sincronização ocasional. Algumas dicas:

- Esta sugestão pode ser um pouco contraintuitiva: **procure desenhar todo o sistema como se ele fosse único e centralizado** - o sistema e base de dados que roda em cada loja é idêntico ao que roda na central. Isso simplifica o desenvolvimento e flexibiliza a implantação, permitindo lojas completamente online, completamente offline ou mais de uma central (centrais regionais), por exemplo.
- Procure deixar tudo transparente para o sistema - ele não precisa saber se os dados que estão sendo lidos foram entrados localmente ou sincronizados remotamente.
- Lembre-se que não possuir conexão de alta disponibilidade é uma decisão de negócio, de modo que a área de negócio optou por outro tipo de investimento (sincronização via ferramentas de infraestrutura e planos de resiliência). Se o sistema tentar arcar sozinho com as consequências de uma limitação física (falta de internet) o projeto fracassará.
- Quais informações serão sincronizadas (o que as lojas recebem e o que enviam) é uma **decisão de negócio**. Veja que o sistema permite isso pelo simples fato de ter sido desenhado como se tudo fosse local.
- Os usuários chave devem estar a par de quais informações dependem da central e também devem estar a par da rotina de sincronização destes dados (por exemplo: as regras de preços são entradas na central na tarde anterior para estarem disponíveis nas lojas na primeira hora do dia).
- Invista pesado em resiliência e monitoramento da sincronização. Os usuários da loja precisam ser alertados, por exemplo, de que os preços para o dia não foram sincronizados, assim o usuário responsável pode por exemplo pedir um fax e entrar manualmente com os preços, repetindo o trabalho que já foi realizado na central, como seria feito no caso de não haver uma central.

Quanto a alta disponibilidade em cada ambiente (central e lojas), embora me pareça secundário na pergunta, você pode selecionar uma das opções do SQL Server, como [cluster](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189134.aspx) ou [espelhamento](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx) de bases de dados.

Comment: Obrigado me parece ser a minha solução.

Answer (score 2):

> O SQL Server possui alguma solução que me ajude com isso?

Não é fácil afirmar. Estas coisas precisam de um estudo aprofundado e ninguém na internet poderá lhe dizer com propriedade algo que realmente te ajude.

Até onde eu sei não tem nada pronto no SQL Server. Ele tem uma série de recursos que usados em conjunto pode facilitar um pouco, mas você terá que criar sua solução, será trabalhoso.

Reforço que o primeiro passo é ter o problema muito bem definido, analisar tudo o que está acontecendo de errado.

Mesmo com o diagnóstico e prognóstico corretos, quando for implantar pode descobrir que não funciona como esperava. Então é complicado cravar que você deve usar algo.

> Trabalhar offline nessa minha situação é o ideal?

Só você sabe disto. Está tudo funcionando bem? Então parece ser o suficiente. Não precisa procurar o ideal se está te atendendo tudo.

Você está tendo problemas? Então precisa diagnosticar com detalhes o que está acontecendo para depois procurar por prognósticos.

> Qual caminho seguir?

Novamente só você pode responder isto, qualquer resposta que diga o caminho para você seguir será apenas uma opinião, não terá relevância alguma.

Grosso modo você tem que montar sua aplicação para não depender do banco de dados central estar funcionando. Se isto é viável ou ideal eu não sei. Mas é certo que isto é necessário.

Se não pode resolver o problema da infraestrutura terá que abrir mão de alguma coisa. Pode ser que a sincronização, se bem feita, não cause maiores problemas, mas pode ser que inviabilize algumas coisas que vocês desejam.

Não existe milagre. Da mesma forma que você não consegue rodar o último World of Warcraft em um 386, você não pode manter alta disponibilidade real com infraestrutura deficiente.

Eu duvido que você consiga resolver o problema de sincronização apenas com recursos do SQL Server.

Claro que se no fundo os banco de dados são descentralizados nas unidades e só concentra os dados centralmente (não parece ser o caso pelo relato) aí fica mais fácil. Mas acho que já está fazendo isto. Talvez você não aceite as desvantagens disto mas não acho que tenha algo que possa ser feito além de garantir a boa sincronização.

Imagino que já leu a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb510414(v=sql.105)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Tenho dúvidas se qualquer uma delas resolve seu problema. Acho que você já percebeu isto.

Me desculpe se isto não responde exatamente ao que você quer mas não é fácil dar uma resposta expressiva em uma pergunta genérica.

Se no meio do processo tiver problemas mais específicos provavelmente dariam boas perguntas. Espero que outras possa dar mais algumas informações relevantes que não sejam sugestões sem sentido.